# styling elements with Javascript without being noticed

Tags: javascript, css, styling

I have a webpage which has content layout like 1,2,3 in markup (and also for no-js
) while **visually** I want it to be 2,3,1.

I'm using Javascript (jQuery) to swap their position. But the problem is, the Javascript code is executed after page loads and therefore the swap process can be obviously seen.

The only solution (and a bad one) I can think of now is to hide the whole body first and restore body when the swap is done.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#div2, #div3").insertBefore("#div1");
    $("body").css({display: "block"});
});
```

```html
<body style="display: none;">
...
<div id="div1">...</div>
<div id="div2">...</div>
<div id="div3">...</div>
...
<!-- in case JS is disabled, use css to restore -->
<!-- style should not be here, that's why I said it's a bad one. -->
<style type="text/css">
body {display: block !important;}
</style>
</body>
```

Anyone got a better idea?

Comment: If you initially hide the body, browsers with JS disabled will not be able to see anything at all.

Comment: Why not just hide the DIVs instead of the entire body?

Comment: @gAMBOOKa I did include a style to restore body right before </body> in case JS is disabled. but like I said, it's a bad way to do so against w3 specs.

Comment: @mblase75 hiding DIVs is not going to help, the time you *show* those DIVs, you'll see the *animation-like* process. I just want everything to be shown at one time, like a real static page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try executing JavaScript instantly after those three elements:

```
<div id="div1">...</div>
<div id="div2">...</div>
<div id="div3">...</div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> $("#div2, #div3").insertBefore("#div1"); </script>
```

Of course, it's a pollution of your HTML, but, in any case, it's better than hiding the whole `body` element (the page will flicker in some old browsers).

Comment: Thanks floatless, that works, but...I lied about "_I have a webpage_", there are actually a few (PHP) pages...which means I have to pollute HTML in each page. Instead of mixing scripts and content, I'v decided to just make the swap a real animation (slide).